# Infrom Selenium that feature file starts \ ends

Tags: selenium, junit, tags, cucumber, language-features

I have to make some operations when a `Feature` file starts or ends.
But I didn't find any way that `Selenium` can know it.

Meanwhile I use a specific `hook tag` to catch the beginning and another one to catch the end. But Is there a way to know it in `Selenium` code?

Comment: Use `junit`, `@Before` and `@After` tags

Comment: @LINGS no. These tags run every `scenario`, but I have some `Scenario`s in a single `feature` file. I want the code will run when the `feature` ends

Comment: do you use capybara?

Comment: @MesutGüneş Cucumber+Selenium

Comment: @Aharon check my answers below, hope it works

Comment: @MesutGüneş see the comment I wrote there

Answer (score 0):

You can use **before** and **after** hook to perform some actions, you can add extra tag to your cucumber scenario and check it by `scenario.getSourceTagNames()`. see the example below:

```
@Before
public void setUpScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    List<String> tags = scenario.getSourceTagNames();
    if (tags.contains(scenario_specific_tag)) {
        System.out.println("Before your scenario running ...." );
    }
}

@After
public void endUpScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    List<String> tags = scenario.getSourceTagNames();
    if (tags.contains(scenario_specific_tag)) {
        System.out.println("After your scenario ...." );
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I can do it. I can also write `@after("@lastScenario")`, as it written today. But the tester who writes the scenario has to: 1. not forget it, 2. add it in the written scenario.
I ask my question to enforce the Selenium do the operations even if it isn't written. Isn't it possible somehow?